# Trying to launch batch file from powershell, and immediately closes

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, server

The command sometimes succesfully launches the batch file however, sometimes it doesn't work and it immediately closes.

When I launch the batch file directly from either cmd or by double clicking the file, it always works flawlessly.

I was wondering what I could do to fix this issue.

#a couple of the commands I have tried

```
start-process -wait -filepath "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" -argumentlist "/c 'C:\path\stream3.bat' .\refresh.bat"

start-process -wait -filepath "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" -argumentlist "/c 'C:\path\stream3.bat'"
```

#The contents of the batch file

```
ffmpeg -loglevel error -i "rtmp://mystream" -vf "scale=426:240,boxblur=luma_radius=1:chroma_radius=1" -vcodec libx264 -an -r 25 -b:v 550000 -crf 31 -sc_threshold 0 -f hls -hls_time 5 -segment_time 5 -hls_list_size 5 "C:\nginx\srv\hls\stream3\output.m3u8"
```

Comment: `cmd.exe` struggles to find the file `'C:\path\stream3.bat'`. `'` has no special meaning in cmd (There isn't a drive named `'C:` and there  isn't a file with extension `.bat'`

Comment: I suggest opening a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/), running `cmd /?` and reading the output usage help of the *Windows Command Processor* in addition to reading the correct problem description above written by Stephan and making the necessary correction.

Comment: The batch file with the single command line and therefore the usage of `cmd.exe` is obviously completely unnecessary because of the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) called by `powershell.exe` to run `cmd.exe` which calls also `CreateProcess` for running `ffmpeg.exe` with the specified arguments does not work different just because of being called by `powershell.exe` instead of `cmd.exe`. PowerShell can run `ffmpeg.exe` also with calling `CreateProcess`.

Comment: There should be additionally read the PowerShell documentation page [about quoting rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) and the other pages referenced at the bottom in __see also__ block. The quoting rule for `cmd.exe` is more simple: `"` not escaped with `^` marks the beginning of a quoted argument string within all characters including `^` are interpreted literally with exception of `%` and of `!` on delayed variable expansion enabled. The double quoted argument string ends on next found `"` or end of line.

Comment: If all you are doing in each batch file is running one `ffmpeg` command, then I would strongly advise that you start your entire project over. You have asked many questions about running several batch files in parallel, and being able to kill and restart each of their child processes as needed. All you had to do was start multiple ffmpeg.exe commands in parallel from powershell, capture their processid's at that time, and restart them as needed. You've made the entire process much more complicated for no good reason. There was no need to involve batch files or `cmd.exe` in your project at all.